# Jinja2 loop creating duplicates

Tags: python, loops, flask, html-table, jinja2

I am trying to create a table using data from a few arrays that I have for my Flask webapp.

I am using two loops -- first to loop through the variables to create the rows; second to loop through the array itself to get the different positions. This works for the most part but it is looping too much? My results are the same thing just 3 times.

```
<table id="example-datatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Discount %</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    {% for record in invoice %}
    {% set length = (invoice | length)-1 %}
    {% for i in range(0, length) %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item codes"][i]}}</td>
        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item quantities"][i]}}</td>
        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item prices"][i]}}</td>
        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item discount %s"][i]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

These are the results I get. It's *correct*, but just replicating three times and not just once.

[image: Results]

I am to the point now where I think I have looked at it so much that I am blind to the problem.

Comment: I'm puzzled why `record` is used in the outer loop, but is ignored in the inner one.

Comment: Hi Dave, not sure honestly. I am a bit new to this so it's mostly just me copying and pasting code from around and editing it to work. :/ Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix it with taking out a loop... dumb fix. but glad to have it fixed!

Edited code:

```
<table id="example-datatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Item</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Discount %</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    {% set length = (invoice | length)-1 %}
                                    {% for i in range(0, length) %} 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item codes"][i]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item quantities"][i]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item prices"][i]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{invoice["fields"]["Account item discount %s"][i]}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
```